# How to prevent duplicate execution of redux toolkit dispatch in useEffect in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using the rudux toolkit in react. After rendering the first page, useEffect is executed and the farmloadPost action is executed.

By the way, armloadPost.pending is executed three times. How can I make it run only once?
i tried disabled stricmode, but it same
this is my code

```
useEffect(  () => {
    dispatch(farmloadPost());
  }, [dispatch]);



  export const farmloadPost = createAsyncThunk(
    "farm/farmloadPost",
    async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(api);
        return response.data;
      } catch (error: any) {
        console.log("error:",error);
        return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
      }
    }
  );



const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: "post",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) =>
    builder

      // loadPost
      .addCase(farmloadPost.pending, (state) => {
        state.farmLoading = true;
        state.farmDone = false;
        state.farmError = null;
      })
      .addCase(farmloadPost.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        // console.log("action.payload:", action.payload);
        state.farmLoading = false;
        state.farmDone = true;
        state.farm = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(farmloadPost.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.farmLoading = false;
        // state.farmDone = action.error.message;
      })

      .addDefaultCase((state) => state),
});
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe because of strictmode ?

Comment: @KcH  i tried disabled stricmode, but it sama

Comment: oh wait, do you mean if you add a log for response or error it prints thrice ?

Comment: @KcH yes i updated my quesion please see

Comment: No, not this I mean response is printed thrice ? put a log in try block, as the promise will be pending and then resolved/rejected so the logs are printed ....

Comment: @KcH yes you're right i prinited third

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(farmloadPost());
 }, []);
```

You should remove the dispatch from the dependency array, and it will fix the issue.